# Facebook debugger / linter gives "extraneous property" error suddenly even though nothing changed

Tags: facebook, debugging, comments, app-id

I have a few blogs that use Facebook comments. They all use the same code to implement the comments box plugin and the meta tags. The only thing that changes between them is the og:app_id property.

After several weeks of working just fine, this weekend, one of the blogs started getting this error in the Facebook Linter / Debugger:

> "Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:app_id."

This seems to be causing the linter to miss other tags (such as the og:description tag, which is clearly defined in the HTML but shows up blank).

Also, because Facebook is rejecting the app_id property, it is not connecting to our app, causing three big problems:

1. the comments box isn't using our settings set through the comments moderator tool; It just uses the defaults
2. We no longer get notifications when someone comments, because the notifications are set up through the comments moderation tool
3. We can't even see comments in the comments moderation tool. We have to go to the page itself to discover whether comments have been made, and moderate them.

Of my several blogs that use Facebook comments, this is the only one giving this trouble, even though the meta tag codes are essentially the same.

Has anyone found a way to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tag is `<fb:app_id>` not `<og:app_id>` See if that helps. Make sure you have got both the namespaces as well

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how that got changed in this one site, but I might not have ever noticed otherwise.